# Notice: Array to string conversion , Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting "Notice: Array to string conversion" errors since I changed a field in my table. I think I made a mistake in changing my entity (which was an integer before)

```html
  /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=false)
     */
     protected $sector = array();
.
.
.
.

 /**
 * Set sector
 *
 * @param array $sector
 * @return Promotion
 */
public function setSector($sector)
{
    $this->sector = $sector;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sector
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getSector()
{
    return $this->sector;
}
```

Stack Trace:

```html
[1] Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO promotions (articleid, name1, name2, suppliername, picture, datefrom, dateto, position, highlight, category, sector, adminid, entrydate, alterationdate, description, aktion_id, alternative, alternativetext) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["1234567", "IFM N\u00e4herungsschalter kapazitiv KI5023", null, "IFM", "image_5_1234567.jpg", "2015-04-15", "2015-05-22", 1, 2, "75", [2,4], 12429, "2015-05-04 09:47:20", "2015-05-04 09:47:20", "<p>test<\/p>", 1, null, null]:

Notice: Array to string conversion in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138
    at n/a
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php line 47

    at Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(object(ContextErrorException), 'INSERT INTO promotions (articleid, name1, name2, suppliername, picture, datefrom, dateto, position, highlight, category, sector, adminid, entrydate, alterationdate, description, aktion_id, alternative, alternativetext) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array('1234567', 'IFM Näherungsschalter kapazitiv KI5023', null, 'IFM', 'image_5_1234567.jpg', '2015-04-15', '2015-05-22', '1', '2', '75', array('2', '4'), '12429', '2015-05-04 09:47:20', '2015-05-04 09:47:20', '&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;', '1', null, null))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 140

    at Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 277

    at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 929

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(object(ClassMetadata))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 318

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(null)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 355

    at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/src/xyz/ShopBundle/Controller/OfferWeekController.php line 305

    at xyz\ShopBundle\Controller\OfferWeekController->offerweekAction(object(Request), '0')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(OfferWeekController), 'offerweekAction'), array(object(Request), '0'))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2770

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2744

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2874

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2175

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 30

[2] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Array to string conversion in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138
    at n/a
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138

    at Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle('8', 'Array to string conversion', '/server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php', '138', array('params' => null, 'logger' => object(LoggerChain)))
        in  line 

    at PDOStatement->execute(null)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 138

    at Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 277

    at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 929

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(object(ClassMetadata))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 318

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit(null)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 355

    at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/src/xyz/ShopBundle/Controller/OfferWeekController.php line 305

    at xyz\ShopBundle\Controller\OfferWeekController->offerweekAction(object(Request), '0')
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(OfferWeekController), 'offerweekAction'), array(object(Request), '0'))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2770

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2744

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2874

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2175

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /server/xyz/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 30
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So why did you need to change the type of the `sector` column? It was used to persist a sector _number_ but now you make that value an array instead of a number in your PHP code.

Comment: @Burnt could you check the type of your column since you updated the field column and ran the `doc:schema:update` command? By the way, I would suggest you to use http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html since it helps about migrating/reverting easily.

Comment: @Marcell: i need to map articls to sectors of our enterprise (mostly to all 4). My predecessor saved each article for each sector, which seemed redundant to me. So I tried to save the sectors as an arry (my guess is, "simple_array" would be sufficient)

Comment: @Ninir: Table was altered correctly, field is now "longtext" with comment

Comment: Could you run `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` to be sure that the mapping is OK, and then dump $sector in your setSector please?

Comment: here´s what i get, when i dump  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($form->get('sector')->getData());         : array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) }
I checked checkboxes 2 and 4, array looks like i expected... by the way, the mappings are ok

Comment: OK, if I convert the array I get from my form into a string and pass that string ($sector) to the DB via setSector, it works. But shouldn't setSector expect an array to pass?

Comment: Another funny thing: when I dump getSector (and the string/array/whatever)in my field is "1,2,3,4", the dump ist an integer (1). Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`array` column type do exists.

But Doctrine store a comment in your database. This comments helps him to know what to do with your data.

I think you can run the `php app/console doctrine:shema:update --dump-sql` command. It will propose you an `ALTER` command that you have to run.

After that, it should works fine ;)

Comment: Already did what you proposed, it still doesnt work (it altered the field to "longtext" an added a comment)  sorry, posting comments here is kinda confusing

Comment: What `$sectors` do you inject in `setSector` ? Is it `[2, 4]` or something else ?

Comment: the dump of my form input looks like this: array(2) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) }, so yes, what i inject should look like what you wrote

Comment: Well that's weird. Maybe you ccan use the `simple_array` type or the `json_array` to see if it's better (the `simple_array` seems fine for me as you insert just unindexed integers)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple_array remark, it's working now. I do have a follow-up question though: I need to change a query, where i check if an integer (Parameter1, sector from customer data) is in my sector-array. before, it looked like this:  $qb->andWhere('p.sector = ?1'); $qb->setParameter(1, $this->contact->getCompanyarea());        is  $qb->andWhere('?1 in (p.sector)';    the correct way?

Comment: Well if you have to filter, then your schema is not good.
The good way to do this is to have a OneToMany relation on your "Area".

This way you can make a JOIN between your tables to filter.

The `simple_array` trick (as the array though) works only if you want to display things, not filter them.

There is a dirty way to do this with a `area LIKE '%?1%'` but it will lead you to a lot of bugs. You should create another table with your areas.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my intention: "Companyarea" is an integer (is either 1,2,3 or 4) and i want to check if it exists in my array ("sector")

Comment: Hmm I think I undestood well. In your database, you should have something like `[2,4]` in your "sector" column. But if you want to list all company in the sector `2`, well you can't ^^. The correct to do this is to have a Sector database, your Company database and a "ManyToMany" relationship between them.

Comment: I have products that are assigned to one or more "sectors" of our company. our customers are only assigned to one "sector". I wanted to check if a product should be displayed to a certain customer (if "customer sector" is in "product-sector-array"). anyway, i think it  might be working already. Thanks again for yur help and patience!

Comment: Ok, so your query seems good. You may have to `explode` your array to make it SQL compatible.

Answer (score 0):

To store an array in the database, convert into a json encoded string and then store in the array. So, modify the getter and setter like this

```
 /**
 * Set sector
 *
 * @param array $sector
 * @return Promotion
 */
 public function setSector($sector)
 {
    $this->sector = json_encode($sector);

   return $this;
 }

/**
 * Get sector
 *
 * @return array
 */
 public function getSector()
 {
   if($this->sector){
      return json_decode($sector);
  }    
  return null;
 }
```

Comment: Your code should not handle this as Doctrine is already doing it for your since you can define 3 types: `array`, `simple_array`, `json_array`.

Comment: I also highly suggest not to polute the entity classes with json_encode and json_decode.

Comment: @tomazahlin mind elaborating why json encode and decode pollutes the entity class?

Comment: @Dheeraj, entity classes "should" only be as simple as possible, ideally only used to hold the data. Mostly they should contain properties, along with their getter/setter methods. If you need to do some json encoding in your entity classes, you are violating single responsibility principle. But it really depends on your case. If this is the simplest and quickest solution, which saves you a lot of effort and which works, why not use it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

My situation was different, but resulted in a similar error. I got it in a `SQL` query when trying to limit my answer to just one using '->setMaxResults()->getResult();`.

Turns out `getResult()` needed to be `getSingleResult()`.

It was returning an array of `Entity` objects, rather than just the one `Entity` object I wanted. Using `getSingleResult()` fixed the error for me.